# How to stop a menu from flickering incontrolably when restarted?

Tags: c, menu, console

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int frstEscolha;
do{
    printf("\n\n WELCOME \n\n");
    printf(" 1- JOGAR \n");
    printf(" 2- SAIR \n");
    scanf ("%d", &frstEscolha);
    printf ("%d %d",s1,s2);
        switch (frstEscolha) {
            system ("cls");
            int sndEscolha;
            case (1):
            s1 = 1; 
            printf ("\n\n  NUMBER OF PLAYERS  \n\n");
            printf ("1- ONE PLAYER \n");
            printf ("2- TWO PLAYERS \n");
            scanf ("%d", & sndEscolha);
            system ("cls");         
            do{
                switch (sndEscolha) {
                    char *trdENome , *trdENome1, *trdENome2;     
                    case (1):
                        s2 = 1;
                        printf ("\nPLAYER NAME:      \n");
                        scanf ("%s", &trdENome);
                        printf("\nGOOD GAME %s \n\n",  &trdENome);

                    case (2):
                        s2 = 1;
                        printf ("\nPLAYER 1 NAME      \n");
                        scanf ("%s", &trdENome1);
                        printf ("\nPLAYER 2 NAME      \n");
                        scanf ("%s", &trdENome2);
                        printf("\nGOOD GAME %s e %s \n\n", &trdENome1, &trdENome2);

                    default : 
                        printf ("Invalid character, try again!!");
                        s2 = 0; 
                }
            }
            while (s2==0);                
        case (2): exit (0);
        default :
            printf ("Invalid character, try again!!"); 
            s1 = 0;
        }
}
while (s1 == 0);
return 0;
}
```

This is supposed to print a menu and let you choose your options to navigate the different menus, the while is used for repeating the process when the character inserted is not valid, but when this happens the console starts flickering and the program chrashes. How is this caused, and how can i fix it?
Thanks

Comment: when you are posting code to an english site please translate the strings in the code, it will be much easier for people to understand and read it.

Comment: I found your error. If you input a character in the first `scanf` statement, the code is running non-stop and it's breaking itself. @SelmanGenç

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, but you must learn and understand pointers. Posted code does not allocate memory for the strings `trdENome`, `trdENome1`, and `trdENome2`. These should probably be arrays, and should also probably be declared in the scope of `main()`. The address operator `&` is used incorrectly; `break` statements should be used in the `switch` statements.

Answer (score -2):

After running your code, nothing seems to flicker uncontrollably and the program runs perfectly fine. Nothing crashes or bugs. The only problem in your code is your `switch` statement. They end up in an infinite loop. What I recommend is to put a `break;` at the end of each case to get out of that loop. Other than that, your code seems to run fine.

> The following code is only to fix the infinite loop problem in the `switch` statement

```
case(1): 
    //your code here
    break;
```

I believed I found the error to your code. In you brief description regarding your problem, I happened to find the error. In you first `scanf`, if the user inputs a character, the program breaks. *My compiler kept on repeating the question.*

What I recommend is to use `if/else` loops to solve your problem. Another solution is to change `int frstEscolha` to `unsigned int frstEscolha`. If the user happens to input a char, it could the value for a character without breaking the program. But highly recommend using `if/else` in this case.

If you are using `unsigned int`, the `scan` works like this.

```
scanf("%lf", &varName);
```

Comment: The issue is caused if you enter something different from 1 or 2, can you please try to see if it's only me or if you also get an error?

Comment: @SelmanGenç I'm pretty sure that will work because it is only the inner `switch` that is causing the problem.

Comment: @narusin doesn't break only prevents the code from falling the other case? it doesn't actually break the loop.

Comment: I will check that out @zmirba. But in which part.

Comment: I know that. If you check his code, there is no `break` to get out of his `switch` statement. It will get stuck there infinitely. @SelmanGenç

Comment: the current code quits the switch but the loop keeps running and switch will get executed over and over again. the break doesn't change anything whatsoever.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please tell me why it's downvoted.

Comment: `break` only terminates execution of the smallest enclosing `switch` or iteration statement. There is no need for a `break` to get out of a `switch` statement, only to avoid execution code of remaining cases.

Comment: I downvoted and already told you the reason for maybe ten times.